# React Hook complex states, setting nested values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a react application that sets values after the user searches for a sales report.  The sales report contains information that I'm hoping to store in the main state.

My state looks like this:

```
const [state, setState] = userState({

created_by: 'user_name', 
....
order : {
          sales_order_id: 123,
          required_by: 'date here', 
          ...,
          address: {
             address_line_1: '2 somewhere road',
             address_line2: 'somewhere town',
             ....

          }
          shippingId: 1,
          contact : {
             name: ...,

          }


        }

});

useEffect(() => {
      Will need to update address in here after 
      Sales_order has been searched for 

});
```

The user has to search for a sales order on the form, this number is then stored in the state. Upon the return of the sales order information, I'm provided with a javascript object containing the address amongst other details.

I need to take the address from this and update my main state.  I considered splitting it into three states

```
state 
order 
address
```

Then store the address in the order then the order in the state but I'm struggling to achieve this. Any solutions?

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: something like [immutability helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65029879/react-issues-updating-array-with-usestate-hook/65030455?r=SearchResults&s=1|37.0352#65030455) might be a good option

Comment: @david784 Thank you for the link this makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way I completed this was like this:

```
    const [address, setAddress] = useState({
                                                                                     
                                      address_line_1: null,                                              
                                      ...,
                                      address_postcode: null
        });

    
    const [order, setOrder] = useState({                                                                             
                                      date_required: null,
                                      ..., 
                                      address: null,
                                      contact: null
        });

    const [contact, setContact] = useState({
                                         contact_name: null,
                                         contact_number: null
        });

    const [state, setState] = useState({
                                     number: null,       
                                     ...,
                                     order: null
        });


    useEffect(() => {
        setOrder(prevState => ({...prevState, address: address, contact: contact}));
    }, [address, contact]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setState(prevState => ({...prevState, order: order}));
    }, [order]);
```

The first useEffect take effect until the contact and address are set in my application. In turn, the order isn't set into the main state until the order is set.

Now I can post the state over to my API.

If you like my answer please mark at the correct one. If not please tell me how I can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

To updated nested properties inside your state you can use the spread syntax:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

> The user has to search for a sales order on the form, this number is then stored in the state. Upon the return of the sales order information

Let's assume that you have a code like this that fetches the sales order information.

```
useEffect(() => {
  yourApiService.fetchSelesOrderInfo(salesOrderNumber).then((orderInfo) => {
    const { address } = orderInfo;
    setState(state => ({...state, address }))
  })
}, [salesOrderNumber])
```

To elaborate, you "subscibe" to `salesOrderNumber` changes coming from your form. This value you used to fetch `orderInfo`, which contains the `address`, after which you use that `address` to overwrite the one that you have stored inside your state.
This code is responsible for overwritting the data using old data and new address data: `setState(state => ({...state, address }))`